# Assigning alias to submodules with __import__

Tags: python

I have the following code in my **init**.py which imports all submodules in a folder in my directory.

package/                    # root folder
---folderA/                 # folder folderA
------**init**.py
------a1.py
------a2.py
---main.py

```
parent_module = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))
for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module == '__init__.py' or module[-3:] != '.py':
        continue
    __import__(parent_module+'.'+module[:-3], locals(), globals())
del module
```

so that i can do imports like this

```
import folderA

folderA.a1.func1()
```

However I would like to shorten the function calls so that for "func1" in a1.py I could do

```
import folderA

a1.func1()
```

I tried doing it by assigning an alias to the submodules in _init__.py but that doesnt seem to work

```
parent_module = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))
for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module == '__init__.py' or module[-3:] != '.py':
        continue
    mod_alias = module
    vars()[mod_alias] = __import__(parent_module+'.'+module[:-3], locals(), globals())
del module
```

I am aware that doing imports this way is not necessarily recommended but my package is set up in a way that I have very long filenames and only one function per file so I would like to shorten the function calls.

Comment: `from folderA import a1`?

Comment: I dont want to have to do that since i dont only have a1 in folderA but about 10 files so i dont want to have to specify them all

Comment: Either you use a `from...import` or use a qualified name. You can also do `import folderA as A` to use shorten it to `A.a1.func()`... You could also do `from folderA import *` but importing everything is usually not recommended.

Comment: I am currently doing the alias version (A.a1.func()) which I guess is not to bad since it is explicit. For some reason `from folderA import *` doesnt work for me